# Template.body vs Template.myTemplate

Tags: meteor

I am currently going through the Meteor tutorial (https://www.meteor.com/try), and have come across something about Templates that puzzles me.

In the tutorial, a simple "Todo List" application gets created. In this app, the following HTML is placed into the **simple-todos.html** file:

```
<!-- simple-todos.html -->
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Then, the following JavaScript is placed into the **simple-todos.js** file:

```
// simple-todos.js
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

At this point, the example works exactly as intended. However, as I poke around in the documentation, as well as look at other examples on the web, I have noticed slightly different syntax: using **Template.*myTemplate*** instead of **Template.*body***.

So, out of curiosity, I altered my JavaScript file to read:

```
Template.task.helpers({ ...
```

instead of:

```
Template.body.helpers({ ...
```

However, when I run the application now, the client does not display the data from the collection. I don't get any errors about undefined types, like I do if I misspell the template name in the JavaScript, so it seems that it is resolving the template correctly. But why isn't it getting used or rendered?

And to go a little further: when is it appropriate to use Template.*myTemplate* and when is it appropriate to use Template.*body*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The helpers code only works for the template it's attached too.

So, code that works for `Template.task` will only apply to templates named "task".

Template.*body* is like the one-off that exists because it would be weird if it didn't. It's a way for you to specifically target the `<body>`, even though technically, there's no template named "body".

So, what is going on:

- Parent template = body
- Child template = task

Your logic says:

In the parent template, for each task that we find, render an instance of the child template "task".

If you change your helper from `body` to `task`, you won't get any output at all, unless you mimic the pattern that's already happening:

```
    <template name="task">
      {{#each tasks}}
       do something
      {{/each}}
    </template>
```

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: In addition, you can create helpers which work in all templates with Templates.registerHelper(name, function), as well as access template x's helpers from template y if template y is placed inside of template x.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<body>` is the parent template, and you should treat it as such:

`<template="body>stuff that normally goes in an HTML body here</template>`

When you remove the helpers for the body, then no data gets displayed at all because helpers pass data into the template. And with no helper for the template i.e. the body, you get no data.